# WebJob Azure Queue UniTask

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

Tengo una duda, cuando uso Azure Storage Queue, guardo un Json

```
{"Tipo": "1", "Nombre":"Test"}
```

Y al procesar el mensaje lo hago desde un WebJob, este se ejecuta cada vez que se inserta un cola, y por lo que veo, las ejecuta en paralelo, osea que si hay 4 colas, las lee todas al mismo tiempo, quiero que se ejecute una por una, y que no lea otra hasta que termine de leer la que está procesando.

Comment: como es eso que se "inserta una cola" ? las queues que creas es una sola en esta pones mensajes, lo que crearias son 4 mensajes json en una queue.

Comment: si, asi es. una cola inserto varios json como el que puse, quiero saber como leer esos mensajes uno por uno